# How to get email content from eml file

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 3.6 and the email module to extract the content of some .eml files (Lotus Notes Email Files).

Below is my code:

```js
def parseEmail(emailFile):
    #emailFile is the path of the .eml file
    with open(emailFile, 'rb') as fp:
        policy500 = policy.default.clone(max_line_length=500)
        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy500).parse(fp)

    text = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
    ...
```

However, for some eml files (not all!), the code wlil give error when executing the line `msg.get_body().get_content()` which gives `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_content'`

Why is this happening and how to resolve it? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: `get_payload()` is the correct name I guess.

Comment: I tried but the problem still persist...Also I think `get_content()` is also correct if I only want to get the content of the mail, but I am not sure as I am very new to python...

Answer (score 1):

I also have faced the same issue while reading the email data from .eml file. I have solved this issue by re-downloading the .eml file from Outlook web application.

The first .eml file by which I was facing issue was downloaded from default application I got in my computer (MAIL).